# Boost binary static_visitor and apply_visitor

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have the following code:

```
typedef boost::variant<LandSearchParameter, WaterSearchParameter> SearchParameter;

enum Visibility{
    CLEAR,
    CLOUDY,
    FOG,
    SMOKE
};

class DetectionGenerator : public boost::static_visitor<double>{
public:

    DetectionGenerator(const EnvironmentalFactors& factors);

    double operator()(const LandSearchParameter& land, Visibility vis) const;
    double operator()(const WaterSearchParameter& water, Visibility vis) const;

private:

    const EnvironmentalFactors mFactors;
};
```

but if I try to use it with `boost::apply_visitor` in the following manner:

```
SearchParameter param = globeCover.generateSearch(lat, lon, altitude);
Visibility vis = weather.generateVisibility(lat, lon, altitude, bearing);
DetectionGenerator detectGen(envFactors);
double prob = boost::apply_visitor(detectGen, param, vis);
```

and get the following from gcc:

> error: no matching function for call to `‘apply_visitor(const SearchRescue::DetectionGenerator&, const boost::variant<boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, double, double, double, bool, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, boost::tuples::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t, double, double, double, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&, SearchRescue::Visibility)`

If I attempt to wrap the `Visibility` enum within a `boost::variant` I get the same error only instead of `Visibility` it reads all that junk above and whatever name I chose for the variant.  I've read over the docs on boost for [binary visitation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.binary-visitation) but I'm at a loss.  Due note, all these things are within the same namespace.

**Update**:

It *was* my attempt that was the problem.  Not shown above was that I had the visitor as a `const` variable.  Once I took the `const` out of the picture, it compiled.  Thank you all for trying to help me out.  Wish I could give more upvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Boaz Yaniv's answer is 100% correct. The [`boost::apply_visitor<>` docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html) state directly:

> Overloads accepting two operands invoke the binary function call operator of the given visitor on the content of the given **variant operands**.

Yaniv's suggested approach for remedying that – taking a `Visibility` object in the visitor's constructor – is also the proper fix. You indicated that such an approach did not work for you; I'll warrant that the problem was in your attempt and not in the approach. ;-] Here's code that compiles:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct LandSearchParameter { };
struct WaterSearchParameter { };
struct EnvironmentalFactors { };

typedef boost::variant<
    LandSearchParameter,
    WaterSearchParameter
> SearchParameter;

enum Visibility
{
    CLEAR,
    CLOUDY,
    FOG,
    SMOKE
};

struct DetectionGenerator : boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    DetectionGenerator(EnvironmentalFactors const& factors, Visibility vis)
      : mFactors(factors),
        mVis(vis)
    { }

    double operator ()(LandSearchParameter const&) const { return 0.; }
    double operator ()(WaterSearchParameter const&) const { return 0.; }

private:
    EnvironmentalFactors mFactors;
    Visibility mVis;
};

int main()
{
    SearchParameter param = LandSearchParameter();
    EnvironmentalFactors const envFactors;
    DetectionGenerator const detectGen(envFactors, CLOUDY);
    double const prob = boost::apply_visitor(detectGen, param);
}
```

If this approach continues to fail to work for you then you'll need to edit your question and update it with your actual, current code.

P.S. Your approach of making `Visibility` a single-type `boost::variant<>` should work also, though it seems silly to me. For reference, this compiles:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct LandSearchParameter { };
struct WaterSearchParameter { };
struct EnvironmentalFactors { };

typedef boost::variant<
    LandSearchParameter,
    WaterSearchParameter
> SearchParameter;

enum VisibilityT
{
    CLEAR,
    CLOUDY,
    FOG,
    SMOKE
};

typedef boost::variant<VisibilityT> Visibility;

struct DetectionGenerator : boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    explicit DetectionGenerator(EnvironmentalFactors const& factors)
      : mFactors(factors)
    { }

    double operator ()(LandSearchParameter const&, VisibilityT const) const
    { return 0.; }

    double operator ()(WaterSearchParameter const&, VisibilityT const) const
    { return 0.; }

private:
    EnvironmentalFactors mFactors;
};

int main()
{
    SearchParameter param = LandSearchParameter();
    EnvironmentalFactors const envFactors;
    DetectionGenerator const detectGen(envFactors);
    Visibility vis = CLOUDY;
    double const prob = boost::apply_visitor(detectGen, param, vis);
}
```

Comment: You're right.  It was my approach.  The visitor was a const variable and that, ultimately, is what caused the issue.  I gave you the answer since you presented a version of the code which compiled, forcing me to diff your code from mine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

boost::apply_visitor only takes a visitor that takes a single argument, so it won't accept your visitor. You may be able to fix it with some binding, but I think a nicer solution would be just to add the Visibility argument at your DetectionGenerator class constructor:

```
class DetectionGenerator : public boost::static_visitor<double>{
public:

    DetectionGenerator(const EnvironmentalFactors& factors, Visibility vis);

    double operator()(const LandSearchParameter& land) const;
    double operator()(const WaterSearchParameter& water) const;

private:

    const EnvironmentalFactors mFactors;
    const Visibility mVis;
};

SearchParameter param = globeCover.generateSearch(lat, lon, altitude);
Visibility vis = weather.generateVisibility(lat, lon, altitude, bearing);
DetectionGenerator detectGen(envFactors, vis);
double prob = boost::apply_visitor(detectGen, param);
```

And as for binary visitation, I don't think this is what you're looking for. It allows apply_visitor to take two arguments, but *both* arguments must be variants.

Comment: That is not correct.  You need to take a look at the documentation about binary visitation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.binary-visitation

Comment: Read my edit - binary visitation is only for visiting two variants of the same type, or two variants of different types. It's not useful for visiting a variant and a non-variant, and it's not a good idea to make Visibility part of a variant just for that.

Comment: Still get the same error.  See what I wrote above.  However, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Very strange indeed... It can't be you forgot to include the "<boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp> header by chance, right? A code like I described above is definitely working for me, though not on GCC.

Comment: BTW, you've said you get *the same* error as above? You shouldn't get the same one with my code. The last part (`SearchRescue::Visibility`) definitely can't be there if you don't call boost::apply_visitor with a Visibility parameter.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv If I name the `typdef boost::variant<Visibility> VarVis` I get the message such like it appears but with "VarVis" substituted for "Visibility".  As to the include, I've got `#include <boost/variant.hpp>` which should include it all, no?

Comment: btw, +1 for trying to help.  Always glad to have another set of eyes on the problem.